# PHP NULL vs 'NULL'

Tags: php, html

The code below prints out a dropdown box with the default string being `--Select Status--` with a value of NULL.

```
print("<label>Overall Status Overwrite:</label>
       <select name='case_ov_status' class='case_ov_status'>
       <option selected='selected' value=NULL>--Select Status--</option>");
```

When the form has been submitted, it will call a function which will determine whether to `dropdown` box as default value, if not I will update SQL database.

However, this is where I'm confused, the if statement below will still RUN despite submitting a value of `NULL`.

I found out 2 hours later that by using `if($case_ov_status != 'NULL')` instead of `if($case_ov_status != NULL)` solved the problem.

```
if($case_ov_status != NULL){ //Still ran despite != NULL.
                mysql_query("START TRANSACTION", $connection);
                $sql = "Update cases set status=".$case_ov_status." Where patientid='".$patientID."' and caseid='".mysql_real_escape_string($case)."'";
                $resultNew = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

This may sound really basic, but can someone explain how this works? As I am still learning.. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: the value that the form submits is a string so 'NULL' would work and NULL which means the literal null value a.k.a empty or not set will not work because there is a string with a value of 'NULL'.. so its not really NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

NULL is a special value to represent unallocated objects in php. "NULL" is a string literal containing the word NULL and is not the same. In PHP however you may see that it will do some type juggling with equality. For example, "" == NULL is true.

You cannot send a PHP NULL value over HTTP since everything is a string in HTTP. So your form even though you specify NULL as a value, will actually send "NULL" to the server.

Answer (score 1):

`value=NULL` is equivalent to `value="NULL"`.  You can't submit non-string values over HTTP.  Instead of `value=NULL` use `value=""` (empty string).  This is falsy for php just like `NULL` is.

Answer (score 1):

All inputs are ALWAYS represented as `string` data.

You just have to fill your values with correct values, it cannot be of type `null`, neither `int` or smth else.

Possible workaround for you:

- Cast every input to integer, if you expect an integer. Like `$id = (int) $_GET['id'] ;`
- Use such functions as `empty()`. It will return true on `"0"`, `0`, `null` and some other.

Answer (score 1):

you have gotten confused here.

NULL != 'NULL'

The null on the left is a reserved value for a variable that has no value, 
The nul on the right is a string containing the word null.

Now to get to your example provided, if you changed your if statement to != 'NULL' (with quotes) you will get your expected result.
if($case_ov_status != "NULL")

My advice however would be to set that value in the option tag to value="" or value="0" and then change your if statement to either :
if($case_ov_status != "")
if($case_ov_status != 0)
or even better
if(!empty($case_ov_status))

Answer (score 1):

when user select `<option selected='selected' value=NULL>--Select Status--</option>");`, it returns the value you specified in `value` attribute. it could be 1,2,abc,..or `NULL`. the string `NULL` returns as selected value.
when you check `if($case_ov_status != NULL)`, it says `$case_ov_status` is set to NULL value (that is "") or not? but obviously you need to check if selected value is NULL `string`. so you have to say `if($case_ov_status != 'NULL')`